# Typescript : Can't set default parameter value as false

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I've a method which has some optional parameters, like this ,

```
initializeInteraction(opts: { type?: string; freehand?:boolean= false }) {
    this._draw = this.drawService.initDraw({ drawtype: opts.type });
    this._drawInteraction = this._draw.interaction;
    this.mapService.addVector(this._draw.vector);
    this.mapService.addInteraction(this._drawInteraction);
  }
```

I want to set the value of `freehand` as `true` only when needed , otherwise I want it as `false`,

but when i declare this

```
initializeInteraction(opts: { type: string; freehand?:boolean= false }) {}
```

Im getting an error as

```
[ts] A type literal property cannot have an initializer. [1247]
```

Comment: '{ type: string; freehand?:boolean= false }' you are declare the type so you can't do inlization for the property but you can use javascript destruction to get the value and pass a default value check my answer 

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You just need to set the default value of freehand no need for `?` it's already optional consider this

```
function initializeInteraction(type: string, freehand: boolean = false) {
 console.log(type,freehand);
 // your magic
}

initializeInteraction('something');
initializeInteraction('something', false);
initializeInteraction('something', true);
```

the only advantage of making the parameters as object is you can pass them with different order

```
function initializeInteraction(opt:{ type:string , freehand?:boolean}) {
  let { type, freehand = false } = opt;
  console.log(type,freehand); 
  // your magic
}
```

you can short the function above like this

```
function initializeInteraction({type,freehand=false }: {type:string,freehand?:boolean}) {
  console.log(type,freehand);
  // your magic
 }
```

pass the parameter as object

```
initializeInteraction({ type: 'something', freehand: false });
initializeInteraction({freehand: false, type: 'something' });
initializeInteraction({type: 'something' });
```

both ways will give the same result  , but they call initializeInteraction differently

`f('') ,f('',true)` or `({type:'',freehand:true}) f({freehand:true,type:''}) , f({type:''})`

Answer (score 3):

Do you really need to wrap `type` and `freehand` up in the `opts` object?

I'd suggest this:

```
initializeInteraction(type: string, freehand?: boolean = false) {
    this._draw = this.drawService.initDraw({ drawtype: type });
    this._drawInteraction = this._draw.interaction;
    this.mapService.addVector(this._draw.vector);
    this.mapService.addInteraction(this._drawInteraction);
}
```

would work for the current implementation of `initializeInteraction`.

Edit:

The other option would be to use overloads...

```
initializeInteraction(type: string);
initializeInteraction(freehand: boolean);
initializeInteraction(type: string, freehand: boolean);
initializeInteraction(param1: string | boolean, param2: boolean = false) {
    //type checking and implementation here...
}
```

This would allow you to pass either one of your values alone, or both.

Comment: Yes , I want to wrap it , Because if you didn't wrap it , you always wants to keep the order when invoking your method , for example  and if I want to omit first variable if I call your method like this initializeInteraction(true) it will make error , because the first parameters is string

Comment: and created a workaround like this ,  initializeInteraction(opts: { type?: string; freehand?: boolean }) {
    this._draw = this.drawService.initDraw({
      drawtype: opts.type,
      freehand: opts.freehand || false
    });
    this._drawInteraction = this._draw.interaction;
    this.mapService.addVector(this._draw.vector);
    this.mapService.addInteraction(this._drawInteraction);
  }

Comment: you can't set the parameter as optional when you give it a default value `Parameter cannot have question mark and initializer.`

Answer (score 1):

```
{ type: string; freehand?: boolean = false }
```

This type literal performs the same role as an *interface* and therefore can't provide a default value. Fortunately, the value of `freehand` will be undefined (falsey) by default.

You can safely replace this with

```
initializeInteraction(opts: { type?: string; freehand?:boolean }) {
    // ...
    if (opts.freehand) {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```